# Two file system mini filter driver registered and started but only first driver works fine and second driver doesn't work.

Tags: windows, filesystems, driver, sysinternals, minifilter

I have written file system mini-filter drive code in which I have registered the IRP_MJ_CREATE routines pre and post operation callback. Same thing I have done for second mini filter driver.
The difference between the two driver is the only the logs (DbgPrint) I put to identify the which driver loads first and receives the first IRP_MJ_CREATE request.
The problem I faced is that the only logs of first driver I can see in Debug View and the second driver loaded successfully but its logs I cant see in the debug view.
I have run the FltMC command in which I found the instance count greater than zero for first driver and instance count zero for second driver.

Comment: What altitude are you setting for the drivers?

Comment: I have set 360000 and 360050 altitudes for both drivers respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance count is zero for the second driver, I believe that would imply that the driver is not attached to any device stacks. Check your code that attaches to drives, or you can call fltmc attach manually.